# Submit button behind options in HTML

Tags: html, html-select, submit-button

I have the following code:

```
<form action="/GetMatch" method="post">
    <select name="FutureMatches" size="5" id="FutureMatchList" style="width: 18%">
        {% for i in range(user_matches|length) %}
        <option value="{{user_matches[i][0]}}}}">{{user_matches[i][1]}} - {{user_matches[i][2]}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="SubmitMatchButton" value="OK"><br>
</form>
```

The problem is that the submit button is behind the options and the only way to make it appear is to insert many `<br>` tags.

Is there an elegant alternative to this?

I am using the latest Edge.

Comment: Assuming the problem is that your select is positioned in an absolute way, browser extract that DOM node from the page, so the button will be behind it. In that case will be easy to solve but maybe you should post the relative CSS code

Comment: @Plastic there is no CSS code that involves the code specified in the question